# Getting google to reindex faster

Tags: spam, cache, google-search-console

We run a high-traffic site for a large organization and it was compromised through an editor account.  The attacker was able to poison the google cache, and the visible result to us is that if you search for us on using Google, the result (and the pages visible through google cache) show us as a drug warehouse.

Our site has been completely audited and is 100% clean now, and we have requested that google reindex our site through their webmaster tools.  Even though google bots hit our site almost constantly, we have yet to see the google cache page get recycled.  Does anyone know anyone know a quicker way to make this happen?  The drug-warehouse page is embarassing to us and our organization.

Answer (score 3):

You cant get Google to crawl faster, but you can provide a site map which allows you to specify updated datetime and update frequency. It is not full proof, but Google will include that in the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

If the Google bots are crawling your new, updated site, then it's really just a matter of time before those results start showing up in the search results.

I am unaware of anthing your can do, short of a direct appeal to Google (good luck getting through to someone!).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to wait for the Google Gods to update their cache.  If you can already see Googlebot crawling your site then it should just be a matter of time.

However, a few new incoming links to your site may just speed things up.  I believe if Google sees more site activity by way of incoming links then it might prompt a slightly faster cache update.  Good luck.